# jQuery attr replacement resulting in undefined context

Tags: jquery

```
  var href = jQuery(balloon_text).find('a').first().attr('href');
   var link = jQuery(balloon_text).find('a').first().attr('href', href + '-' + id);
```

console.log(link) resulting in

> [a, prevObject: $.fn.init[2], context: undefined, selector:
>   "a.slice(0,1)", init: function, jquery: "1.4.4"…]

jQuery(balloon_text).find('a').first() reports a correct a tag.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect/want?

Comment: What is balloon_text here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. When setting an attribute, the returned value is the jQuery object. What you see in the log is the expected behavior.

As a proof, try logging the attribute like that :

```
console.log(link.attr('href'));
```

Comment: How would i replace the original string then?

Comment: @AlxVallejo the original string is replaced, it's just that you are not logging what you think!

Comment: If i console.log(balloon_text) the string is not replaced

Comment: @AlxVallejo Well, i don't know what is balloon_text, but that's not what you are modifying. You are modifying the href of the first `a` inside balloon_text.

Comment: So how do i find the a tag in balloon text and replace it?

Comment: @AlxVallejo Replace it with...? Can you make a Fiddle? It will be easier to help.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Alright, here a working code : http://jsfiddle.net/TwXkX/2/ (I've removed the var id since it was undefined). The major problem was that balloon was a string, which mean no matter what you do, nothing will change at the end. Convert it in a jQuery object and use `.append()`.

Comment: Thanks, how would i convert it back to a string then?>

Comment: Well, `balloon_text = balloon_text.outerHTML()` work, but i don't see why you need it as a string.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did balloon_text = balloon_text.html() to make it back into a string. I was feeding that string as an html output variable.